# Windows 10, Kiosk Mode, Shortcuts do not work

Tags: windows-10, kiosk

I'm taking over a project for Windows 10 Kiosk Mode Multi App.

I followed (I believe) all the instructions listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps

I have created an XML file with a list of allowedapps, then the layout section.  Also in the XML file is the account and GUID.

On the layout I have 2 tiles:

- The first tile is a shortcut file to a specific MS Access database, Database1.  per the link, I put a shortcut in this folder: c:\programdata\Microsoft\WIndows\Programs\Start Menu
- The Second tile is a shortcut directly to MS Access.

I create the provision and install it. However, when I click the tile to the database, nothing happens; no warning, no error.  But when I click the Tile to MS Access, it opens MS Access. I can access Database1 this way.  but this is not convenient for the end user.  I'd rather have a tile directly to Database1

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  maybe a specific permission on the Shortcut?

UPDATE: another symptom or detail.  my tech added a tile to the windows explorer to open the path of the database folder.  When that was done, the tiles to the database worked.  however we don't want to provide the path to the database folder.  Could be a user right, but unsure where it got implemented.  maybe Kiosk, maybe kiosk's group policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  It turns out that adding Microsoft Edge as an application tile does not work.  I don't know why.  When I removed MS Edge, all the tiles worked.  So I then created a Internet shortcut (.URL) and put that as a tile.  and then it worked.  just really stinks that the MS Edge can't directly be a tile.